# Is this a Python path issue?

Tags: python

I'm confused about whether or not my Python path is set up correctly. I'm using Ubuntu in a corporate environment so I've been installing packages/modules with the `--user` setting within a `virtualenv` environment (I don't have admin or `sudo` privileges).

```
(my_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ pip install --user browsercookie
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): browsercookie in /home/myUsername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But when I run my file I get:

```
ImportError: No module named browsercookie
```

Other details:

```
(my_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ which python
/usr/share/anaconda/bin/python
```

This is the message I get when I install `browsercookie`:

```
(my_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ python <where setup files are>/setup.py install --user
/usr/share/anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file './__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
copying ./my_file.py -> build/lib/browsercookie
package init file './__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running install_lib
copying build/lib/browsercookie/my_file.py -> /home/myUsername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsercookie
byte-compiling /home/myUsername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsercookie/my_file.py to my_file.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing /home/myUsername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsercookie-0.7.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

And...

```
(my_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ which pip
/usr/share/anaconda/bin/pip
(my_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ pip install browsercookie
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): browsercookie in /home/myUsername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

New environment details:

```
xx@xx:~/environments$ virtualenv new_env
New python executable in new_env/bin/python
Installing distribute.............................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip...............done.
xx@xx:~/environments$ source new_env/bin/activate
(new_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ which virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
(new_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ which pip
/home/username/environments/new_env/bin/pip
(new_env)xx@xx:~/environments$ which python
/home/username/environments/new_env/bin/python
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ideally since you are already into your env my_env you should not be getting this error. You can do one thing but its more of temporary fix. Perform `set PATH = <path_to_virtualenv_python_binary>`. This will enable you to point to `python` of your virtualenv than the one installed by `conda`.

Comment: If you're in an active virtualenv, that doesn't seem like the right python.

Comment: @Varad that is going to screw up your ability to do most things in the shell and is not a good idea. Nor is pointing path to the actual binary going to do anything useful.

Comment: @pvg How do I know which Python it is supposed to point to? Am I supposed to install Python in my virtualenv first?

Comment: @pvg I agree with you, that's why I had mentioned `temporary` to just check if it gives him a repl where he can try out `browsercookie` imports and verify. Also I would not suggest to make this way and run his program.

Comment: @happyspace no, when you activate the virtual env, it's supposed to do all the magic for you, including setting up the appropriate links, etc. You should describe what you're doing step by step, including the creation and use of your venv.

Comment: @Varad it's going to instantly break your shell to the point of unusability. You won't even be able to start python. So no, it's not a temporary solution to anything.

Comment: @happyspace: What does `which pip` say?  Does `pip install browsercookie` give you an error, and if so what does it say?

Comment: @pvg That's my bad. I thought it would work that way for testing atleast. May be I need to check that out. Any ways thanks for pointing.

Comment: You might be able to refer to the same python/pip version by using `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: @happyspace I don't see anything in your edited question about you creating and then activating a virtualenv. You need to do that for virtualenv to do its thing. From what you've posted, it doesn't look like there is an active virtualenv - you wouldn't have to go through most of these hoops if there were. Please post about how you created and activated the virtualenv. If you haven't done that at all, you should.

Comment: @pvg I created the `virtualenv` a while ago so don't have the output of that. Doesn't the parentheses at the beginning with my `virtualenv` name in it `(my_env)` mean that it's activated?

Comment: Make a new new and test. Also do a `which virtualenv`. Make a new one, activate it, see what `which pip` and `which python` tell you when the environment is active.

Comment: How are you importing the module?

Comment: @mwweb `import browsercookie`

Comment: So looks like your old environment was either not activated or hosed in some other way. Just use the new environment which clearly appears to work.

Comment: Conda install browsercookie

Comment: All good now. Thanks @pvg and everyone.

Answer (score 0):

firts you need upgrade your pip installer:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

after you can install the package:

```
 pip3 install browser-cookie3
```

and execute using python3